# Linux can`t create table in mysql workbench

Tags: linux, mysql-workbench, create-table

I`ve installed my sql workbecnh on linux:

[MySqlWorkbench version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvJxy.png)

Using export -> forward engineer get this test script:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Sat 06 Feb 2021 01:14:50 PM EET
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`test`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`test` (
  `idtest` INT NOT NULL,
  `testcoltes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtest`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

And got this error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`test` (   `idtest` INT NOT NULL,   `testcoltes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`idtest`),   UNIQUE INDEX `idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5 0,00027 sec
```

it has created db, but unable to create any table. I wasn`t even participating in creating this script (it was just exported out of the model) so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Should be:

```
UNIQUE INDEX (`idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It doesnt help. Output:
```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`test` (   `idtest` INT NOT NULL,   `testcoltes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`idtest`), UNIQUE INDEX (`idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5 

```

Comment: I changed the line

UNIQUE INDEX `idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE)

to

UNIQUE INDEX (`idtest_UNIQUE` (`idtest` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB;

And it also says '(' is not valid input at this position for this server version